# ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize seems to be ignoring my array :(

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I am working on an existing app that has a nice little helper method that in the end calls ObjectStateFormatter Serialize() - here is the code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Transforms a limited object serialization (LOS)-formatted object into a view-state value and places the results into a <see cref="T:System.IO.TextWriter"/> object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="output">The <see cref="T:System.IO.TextWriter"/> to receive the transformed value. </param><param name="value">The LOS-formatted object to transform into a view-state value. </param>
public void Serialize(TextWriter output, object value)
{
  this.SerializeInternal(output, value);
}

private void SerializeInternal(TextWriter output, object value)
{
  string str = this._formatter.Serialize(value);
  output.Write(str);
}
```

Am I correct to assume that it ignores my property that is a List ?

Thanks
Ken

Comment: What is the output? And what are you expecting?

Comment: Lets say I have a person object with a string Firstname, string Lastname and List<Phone> Phones, it will serialize the first and last name however my list<phone> always comes back empty so when I go to save I have lost access to that data.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is ever wondering - The LosFormatter will indeed serialize a generic list. I just did a small test. That of course leaves me to figure out where in the architecture I just inherited this thing is failing but at least I know it will work. Here is a sample I put together.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    var Person = new Person
                     {
                         FirstName = "Ken",
                         LastName = "N",
                         Phones = new List<Phone>
                                      {
                                          new Phone {Ext = "O", PhoneNumber = "2341234"},
                                          new Phone {Ext = "O", PhoneNumber = "2341234"},
                                          new Phone {Ext = "O", PhoneNumber = "2341234"}
                                      }
                     };
    var serializedPersonObject = LosSerializeObject(Person);
    ViewData["PersonObject"] = serializedPersonObject;
    return View();
}

public ActionResult About()
{
    var personString = Request.QueryString[0];
    var person = (Person) RetrieveObjectFromViewState(personString);
    return View();
}

string LosSerializeObject(object obj)
{
    var los = new System.Web.UI.LosFormatter();
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    los.Serialize(writer, obj);
    return writer.ToString();
}

object RetrieveObjectFromViewState(string serializedObject)
{
    var los = new System.Web.UI.LosFormatter();
    return los.Deserialize(serializedObject);
}
```

Then a button on the Index.ASPX page

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Check this", "About", "Home", new { person = ViewData["PersonObject"] }, null)%>
```

and sure enough the call to Serialize and Deserialize give me list of Phones.